# How to fix highlighted state UIButton delay in UIPageViewController page?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, delay, uipageviewcontroller

I have a screen in which I have a `UIPageViewController` in each page I have a `UIButton`. The problem is that there is a delay of the pressed/highlighted state of the button for about a half second when the user presses the button. both state images are set to the button using the storyboard.

This happens in the Simulator as well as on a real device.

Now from my Google searches, I came across a few posts that describe this issue, for example:

[UIButton delayed state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/788085/uibutton-delayed-state-change)

and:

[UIbutton only looks clicked (highlighted) on longPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41371479/uibutton-only-looks-clicked-highlighted-on-longpress)

In all posts, the solution is to use the `delaysContentTouches` setting and set it to `false`.

**The problem is:** I didn't found how would I apply this in my case of a `UIPageViewController`. most of the posts talk this issue in a `UIScrollView` or a `UITableView`.

**So, the question is:** how would I do that in case of a `UIPageViewController`? I didn't see that `UIPageViewController` has this setting and didn't find any other way to apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution to this issue, This piece of code will fix the button highlighted click delay but will prevent the pager scroll on the button itself.

```
public override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    for view in self.view.subviews {
        if view is UIScrollView {
            (view as? UIScrollView)!.delaysContentTouches = false
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I didn't find this in `UIPageViewController` is that `UIPageViewController` is not a subclass of `UIScrollView` as I expected but it contains it as a subview.